# Makefile link issue

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I can't figure out how link static libraries in Makefiles. I use ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I even tried to use direct path to these libraries, and the issue remains unchanged. Here's my Makefile code.

```
LIB = libgeoms.a

SRC =   mlx_pxl_put.c   \
        std_arc.c       \
        std_crcl.c      \
        std_line.c      \
        std_poly.c      \
        std_rect.c      \

CC = clang
WARNS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
SRCP = /usr/local/wealdboar/src/
INCLUDEP = /usr/local/wealdboar/include/
LIBP = /usr/local/wealdboar/lib/
HEADER = geoms.h
LX11P = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a
LXEXTP = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.a
LMLX = /usr/local/lib/libmlx.a

$(LIB): $(OBJ)
    @echo "Every funtion is compile proved ..."
    @ar rcs $(LIB) $(OBJ)
    @echo  "All functions added to static lib ..."

$(OBJ): %.o :%.c
    @echo "check $< to be right"
    @$(CC) $(WARNS) -c $(LX11P) $(LMLX) $(LXEXTP) $< -o $@

all: $(LIB)

clean:
    @echo "removing all binaries ..."
    @rm -rf $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    @echo "removing static library ..."
    @rm -rf $(LIB)

re: fclean all

install: re clean
    @echo "coping $(LIB) to $(LIBP)"
    @sudo cp $(LIB) $(LIBP)
    @echo "coping sources to $(SRCP)"
    @sudo cp $(SRC) $(SRCP)
    @echo "coping header to $(INCLUDEP)"
    @sudo cp $(HEADER) $(INCLUDEP)
```

[Issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN6r7.png)

Comment: What is "the issue"?  You haven't shown us what happens, what errors you get, what doesn't work, etc.  However, I'll say that libraries are linked into _executables_ and you're trying to link them into _object files_, which cannot work.

Comment: The error is in “issue image”. I can’t build a static library libgeoms.a because I got error: ’clang: error: -l<something>: 'linker' input unused [-Werror, -Wunused-command-line-argument]’

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the `-l` or `-L` flags to tell `clang` to link against choosen libraries.

Comment: i changed  `@$(CC) $(WARNS) -c $(LX11P) $(LMLX) $(LXEXTP) $< -o $@ to `@$(CC) $(WARNS) -c $< -o $@ -L$(LXS) -lX11 -lXext -lm -L$(LMLX) -lmlx`, and also there are two variables `LXS = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `LMLX = /usr/local/lib`. The problem remains: **'linker' input unused** for all static libraries

Comment: ```-L``` flag enables you to add a directory to library search path, you should use ```-l``` instead

Answer (score 0):

First please don't paste image links in StackOverflow.  They aren't searchable, they aren't quotable, and many people are not willing to click a on links to other sites.  Please cut and paste the actual messages.

Second, when working with makefiles you should not use the `@` option which hides the most important information about the commands being run.  It's much harder to debug a makefile when the command lines are not visible.  If you really want to hide the actual commands you should either add in the `@` after everything is already working and not before, or else use [tricks like this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/) to allow for a debug mode.

Finally your error is as I suggested in my comment above.  You are trying to add static libraries to a *compile* command (a command that compiles source files into object files).  Libraries can only be added into *link* commands (commands that convert object files and libraries into executables).

You are not actually creating an executable anywhere in your makefile that I can see, so there's nowhere that you can add libraries here.  But, you need to remove them from the compile rule:

```
$(OBJ): %.o :%.c
        @echo "check $< to be right"
        @$(CC) $(WARNS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks for help. This hint really helped me, now static lib is built. I didn’t know that linkers should be used, when it used to build executables